# Spring Expression Language (SpEL) is not working when hyphen is used

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to parse an expression by using Spring Expression Language.

if *`myVariable`* value is set to "first-name" (value with hyphen) then getting `class.org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException`.

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
String parsedDynamicVariablesValue = parser.parseExpression("#" + myVariable).getValue(stdContext, String.class);
```

how to solve issue with the hyphen?

Reference Used:
[Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Comment: What did you expect "`#first` minus `name`" to be?

Comment: first-name is a variable content/value for myVariable, it is going to set at run-time.

Comment: But in an *expression*, you have operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc. See that second one? The minus sign, aka subtraction operator, aka dash, aka hyphen. That is why a hyphen is not a valid name character, because it's not a hyphen, it's a minus, which means that each side of it are values to be subtracted, exactly like my previous comment said.

Comment: In my case I am not doing any mathematical operations on top of myVariable, I am doing a string replacement by using SpEL.

Comment: What do you think [`parseExpression()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/common/TemplateAwareExpressionParser.html#parseExpression-java.lang.String-) does? Second part of the name is a hint: **Expression**. The javadoc *(if you had bothered to read it)* even shows a good example of an expression: `3 + 4`. Or perhaps `3 - 4`, or `a - b`, or `a-b` would be more on point here. Oh, that last one looks like what you're doing. **Evaluating the expression** `#first - name` *(space added for clarity)*, because that's how the string **parses**.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way, you are trying to parse `#first-name` - just like Java, you can't have hyphens in variable names.

Answer (score 0):

we can provide hyphens or dash in the expressions inside square bracket with quotes. something below like this would work.

String expressionString = "#{response.headers['header-1']}";

Eg:

```
    String response = "{\"response\":{\"headers\":{\"header-1\":\"header2\",\"header1\":\"header1\"},\"body\":{\"body\":\"body\"}}}";
    String expressionString = "#{response.headers['header-1']}";
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
    conversionService.addConverter(new Converter<JsonPropertyAccessor.ToStringFriendlyJsonNode, String>() {
        public String convert(JsonPropertyAccessor.ToStringFriendlyJsonNode source) {
            return source.toString();
        }
    });
    StandardTypeConverter standardTypeConverter = new StandardTypeConverter(conversionService);
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.setTypeConverter(standardTypeConverter);

    JsonPropertyAccessor jsonPropertyAccessor = new JsonPropertyAccessor();
    context.addPropertyAccessor(jsonPropertyAccessor);
    context.setRootObject(response);

    TemplateParserContext templateParserContext = new TemplateParserContext();
    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(expressionString, templateParserContext);
    System.out.println(expression.getValue(context));
```

OUTPUT:
header2