# Problem with put boolean from Thymeleaf to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to show my modal window again when form has errors.
I try to open it by putting variable with value `true` from Thymeleaf to JS.

Fragment of controller code:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("error_msg", "Wprowadzono nieprawidłowe dane!");
    model.addAttribute("whichList", "doc");
    model.addAttribute("form-hasError", true); <------ variable which I want to put.
    model.addAttribute("doctors", doctorService.getAllDoctors());
    return "admin/userCRUD";
}
```

JS fragment in Thymeleaf html file:

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        const formError = /*[[${form-hasError}]]*/ false;
        console.log(formError);
        if (formError)
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    });


    /*]]>*/

</script>
```

Error:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "form-hasError" (template: "doctor/doctorList" - line 123, col 33)
EL1030E: The operator 'SUBTRACT' is not supported between objects of type 'null' and 'null'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Expression Language (SpEL) is not working when hyphen is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122683/spring-expression-language-spel-is-not-working-when-hyphen-is-used). In other words, the `-` in `${form-hasError}` is interpreted as a minus sign. Try using an underscore instead, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames, I swapped `-` with `_` and work perfect.